# Problems with anchor tag - PHP

Tags: php, html

I wrote some code for a real estate website and I have a little problem.

When I click on an ad, I want to make the page go back at the line. In order to do that I use the anchor but it doesn't work.

In the main page I've put this

```
<a href="#<?php echo $do_query[id];?>"></a>
```

In the page of the ad detail I've put this:

```
<a  href="affitti.php?location=<?php echo $do_query[location];?>&&lang=<?php echo $lang;?>#<?php echo $do_query[id];?>" >
```

It has to return at the number id of the anchor, but it doesn't go back either.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Remove one of the `&` in the link

Comment: Also please quote the text inside `[]` with single quotes. Behavior you rely on is discouraged because it uses implicit undefined constant into string conversion(and some day the constant may get defined), and may be removed in the future.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you don't have the anchor per se. Check that  is not missing:

```
 <a name="anchor"></a>
 <a href="#anchor">Click here to go anchor</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

either use the `name` attribute as Marcos explains in his answer or an `id`
see below

```
<a id="<?php echo $do_query[id];?>"></a>
```

and

```
<a href="affitti.php?location=<?php echo $do_query[location];?>&lang=<?php echo $lang;?>#<?php echo $do_query[id];?>" >
```

the first placeholder needs to have an id set and the actual link will reference the placeholder by `#id`